# Is there a way to update device initial twin from azure function app?

Tags: azure-functions, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I'm using custom allocation policy to register my device through DPS. Reference code for C# can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-use-custom-allocation-policies#create-the-custom-allocation-function).

I have ported most of the code for Azure function from C# to NodeJS as below:-

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const regId = req.body.deviceRuntimeContext.registrationId;
    const response = {
        status: 200,
        message: 'Device registered successfully'
    };
    if (!regId)
    {
        response.status = 500
    }
    const requestCustomPayload = req.body.deviceRuntimeContext.payload;
    context.res = {
        iotHubHostName: req.body.deviceRuntimeContext.payload.hubName
    };
}
```

Now, the issue I'm facing is updating the initial twin for the device in above code. If you check the above link for c# code it has an class called TwinState and TwinCollection which are used to update the intial twin of the device, but same classes or similar api's I was not able to find in NodeJS.

Does the nodejs Azure IoT sdk provide a way to update the initial twin?

Comment: the *TwinState* is just a wrapper for *tags* and *desired* properties, see details in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.provisioning.service.twinstate?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @RomanKiss you are right. Following that link i was able to figure out the data to be sent. But the catch is we need to send the data in body field. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the custom allocation in node.js Azure function. Below is the code:-

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const regId = req.body.deviceRuntimeContext.registrationId;
    if(req && req.body && req.body.deviceRuntimeContext && req.body.deviceRuntimeContext.payload && req.body.deviceRuntimeContext.registrationId) {
        const requestCustomPayload = req.body.deviceRuntimeContext.payload;
        context.res = {
            body: {
                iotHubHostName: req.body.deviceRuntimeContext.payload.hubName,
                initialTwin: {
                    tags: {
                            deviceName: "test"
                          }
                    },
                    properties: {
                        Desired: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    } else {
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            message: `Somethig went wrong. Req object is ${JSON.stringify(req)}`
        }
    }
}
```

Some observations in above code

1. The returned object from the function has a body field in which we set the hubName and the Initial twin properties.
2. `D` is caps in the `Desired` field under properties field of initial twin
3. The returned object from function is assigned to context.res

[Here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Internet-of-Things-Show/IoT-Hub-DPS-updates) is the official video from Azure guys.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to initialize IoT Hub device twins when a device is first provisioned by DPS is to use the "initial Device Twin" state feature of the DPS enrollment group.

You define the initial twin state and when a device is provisioned by the enrollment group, the device twin is automatically populated for the new device.

```
{
  "tags": {
    "AnyKey": "AnyValue"
  },
  "properties": {
    "desired": {
        "newKey": 200,
        "newKey2": "this is a test",
    }
  }
}
```